# PHP: How do i remove an element from a multidemision array?

Tags: php

I have this code to add new elements to a multidimension array:

```
$this->shopcart[] = array(productID => $productID, items => $items);
```

So how do i remove an element from this array? I tried this code, but its not working:

```
public function RemoveItem($item)
{
    foreach($this->shopcart as $key)
    {
        if($key['productID'] == $item)
        {
            unset($this->shopcart[$key]);               
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

- **Warning**:  Illegal offset type in unset in **C:\xampplite\htdocs\katrinelund\classes\TillRepository.php** on line **50**

Comment: The first code sample might misses some '-s around the keys.

Comment: @ricebowl: It must be the unset one.

Comment: @erenon, probably, yeah. But I just like to be sure =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public function RemoveItem($item)
{
        foreach($this->shopcart as $i => $key)
        {
                if($key['productID'] == $item)
                {
                        unset($this->shopcart[$i]);   
                        break;                        
                }
        }
}
```

That should do the trick.

**Update**

There is also an alternative way:

```
if ( false !== $key = array_search($item, $this->shopcart) )
{
    unset($this->shopcart[$key];
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the first example. Typo in the second: !== insted of !===, and the second one is much less readable; don't use it if it's  possible.

Comment: It's not a typo, take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php. Less readable? Well, that depends from coder to coder, personally I prefer it.

Comment: Whoa! Ooops, you're right, have to start reading what I write twice before posting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're not enumerating over indices, but values there, to unset an array index, you have to unset it by index, not by value.

Also, If your array index is actually the productID you can eliminate the loop altogether:

```
public function RemoveItem($productID)
{
    if (isset($this->shopcart[$productID]))
    {
        unset($this->shopcart[$productID]);
    }
}
```

Your example doesn't show how you are adding items to `$this->shopcart`, but this may or may not be an option for you depending on the needs of your project. (i.e. not if you need to have seperate instances of the same productid in the cart).